# What language do I use to create drag and drop functionality like Webly?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create something that allows someone to create a site using drag and drop online just like weebly.com. What language is used for this - javascript?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Javascript library with a built-in drag & drop functionality like JQuery. See documentation and examples at http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes. Long answer: You could also use Flash.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why this got -1. It is technically accurate.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript obviously. Flash is history.